# Как можно отобразить контент, вместо приходящего JSON

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

У меня есть список товаров, которые можно фильтровать, но когда я это делаю, с помощью `query`: `?category=all`, то с сервера приходит JSON с товарами прямо на страницу (я знаю, что он приходит на страницу, потому что я его возвращаю), вместо моего контента на сайте.

Можно ли фильтровать товары, с помощью `query` и выводить на страницу только отфильтрованные товары?

Может есть в `nuxt` такая штука с именами файлов, как например `user/_settings` только для `query`?

**Сервер**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Product = require("../models/Product");

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { query: { category } } = req;
    const products = await Product.find();
    const productsByCategory = category === "all" ? products : products.filter(prd => prd.category === category);

    return res.status(200).json({ ok: true, products: productsByCategory });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ ok: false, message: "Произошла ошибка сервера", });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Клиент**

```
const serv = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'http://localhost:3000' : '';

    async fetchProducts() {
      try {
        const data = await fetch(`${serv}/`, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          }
        });

        return data.json();
      } catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    }
```

Comment: А в чём проблема? У Вас есть свойство query в объекте `asyncData(params)` (вариант для SSR). В методах к ним доступ есть через роутер (`this.$route.params`). Как передадите параметры, так и дергайте их оттуда, и передавайте к API. Другими словами, что хотите сделать, то и делайте явно – Nuxt тут не при чем, и магическим образом он не даст ничего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил эту задачу следующим образом:

Добавил `asyncData` и `watch` для слежки за `query`

```
  watch: {
    async "$route.query.category"() {
      const { category } = this.$route.query;

      await this.$store.dispatch("catalog/getProductsByCategory", category);
    },
  },
  async asyncData({ query: { category }, store }) {
    await store.dispatch("catalog/getProductsByCategory", category);
  },
```

UPD: Можно заменить этот кусок следующим кодом: (С помощью `watchQuery` будет перезаписана вся страница при изменении `?category`. [Подробнее](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/pages/#the-watchquery-property))

```
  watchQuery: ["category"],
  async asyncData({ query: { category }, store }) {
    await store.dispatch("catalog/getProductsByCategory", category);
  },
```

После чего отправляю категорию на сервер

```
    async getProductsByCategory({ commit }, category) {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(`${serv}/products/categories`, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Accept-Type": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ category })
        });

        const data = await res.json();

        commit("setProducts", data.products);

        return data;
      } catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    }
```

И вывожу товары с этой категорией

```
router.post("/categories", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { category } = req.body;
    const products = await Product.find();
    const productsByCategory = category === "all" ? products : products.filter(prd => prd.category === category);

    return res.status(200).json({ ok: true, products: productsByCategory });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ ok: false, message: "Произошла ошибка сервера", });
  }
});
```